# How to deselect an already selected item in the react-native-dropdown-picker?

Tags: react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

I'm using [react-native-dropdown-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker) to implement a dropdown in my react-native mobile app.

Following is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { View } from 'react-native';

import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Spain', value: 'spain'},
    {label: 'Madrid', value: 'madrid'},
    {label: 'Barcelona', value: 'barcelona'},
    {label: 'Italy', value: 'italy'},
    {label: 'Rome', value: 'rome'},
    {label: 'Finland', value: 'finland'}
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingHorizontal: 15
    }}>
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setItems}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**This is the output:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLirr.png)

I need to deselect the already selected item, when the user clicks on that selected at the opened dropdown. But could not find any props or method to do so. Thank you so much guys.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might've found a solution, check it out:

```js
import { View } from 'react-native';

import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Spain', value: 'spain'},
    {label: 'Madrid', value: 'madrid'},
    {label: 'Barcelona', value: 'barcelona'},
    {label: 'Italy', value: 'italy'},
    {label: 'Rome', value: 'rome'},
    {label: 'Finland', value: 'finland'}
  ]);
  
   const selectValue =  (currentValue:( ((prevState: string) => string) | string )  ) => {
    let chosenValue = (currentValue as ((prevState: string) => string))()
    if (chosenValue === value) {
      setValue('') // basically here, I reset the value to initial state if the selected value is exactly the same with the previously selected one
    } else {
      setValue(currentValue)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingHorizontal: 15
    }}>
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={selectValue}
        setItems={setItems}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: there is a small concern. In this expression, `let chosenValue = currentValue();`. It gives a typescript error saying, 'This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'string | ((prevState: string) => string)' are callable.
    Type 'string' has no call signatures.'

Comment: Yep, you're right. I updated it: the `currentValue` is now casted to the corresponding type which has a call signature